# Load image from string

Tags: python, pygame

Given a string containing jpeg image data, is it possible to load this directly in pygame?

I've tried using StringIO but failed and I don't completely understand the 'file-like' object concept.

Currently, as a workaround, I'm saving to disk and then loading an image the standard way:

```
# imagestring contains a jpeg

f=open('test.jpg','wb')
f.write(imagestring)
f.close()
image=pygame.image.load('test.jpg')
```

Any suggestions on improving this so that we avoid creating a temp file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fstr = cStringIO.StringIO(simage)
pygame.image.load(fstr, namehint="somethinguseful")
```

Comment: I'm getting a "TypeError: load_extended() takes no keyword arguments" error.

Comment: Without the namehint parameter it seems to be working, I'll do some more testing.

Comment: Hmmm, I have seen that. Guess optional means don't try it unless it doesn't work. Bah.